# How to fix 'couldn't initialize directdraw' in virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox, 3d

I use ubuntu to install virtualbox.

I use virtualbox to install xp and enable 3D on settings and reinstall guest addition on safe mode with 3D support.

Then I install dxwebsetup.exe and reboot.

Why I run game for test it still says 'couldn't initialize directdraw'?

Am I missing something? How to fix it?

Thank you~

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue for a different game.  I believe its the same for most of the older games being run in XP mode in Win7 Pro and above.  Assuming virtual machine and XP mode were properly installed and the game was installed while in XP mode, the fix "should" be relatively easy.

Set the Custom DPI setting to 100% and make sure you are using the native resolution from the screen you're viewing.  This only matters for games running in XP mode.  Apparently, XP mode doesn't like the DPI setting changed from 100%.